# unhex(hex()) function in SQL Injection

Tags: sql, sql-injection

I'm learning about SQL Injection. And sometime I read in some document that we have to use unhex(hex()) function when exploit in URL address.

And my question is, why we have to use it?

Comment: Please provide some examples, its unclear what you mean

Comment: Provide the Code where you are stuck on

Answer (score 2):

First off, **it cannot help you with SQL injection**. If SQL injection is impossible, then no hex/unhex/whatever function will make it possible.

It can only help to exploit an existing SQL injection, when a site is protected by a *very silly* protection method like a black list disallowing a single quote in the input. So these functions can help to avoid using a quote or any other "malicious word" that may alert the filter.

But honestly, I cannot imagine a developer in 2018 using a black list filterig against SQL injection instead of prepared statements for the data/a white list for the everything else